# cannot connect to lwip binded socket address after idle for sometime

Tags: sockets, tcp, freertos, lwip

I am using lwIP under FreeRTOS, the IP server runs on an ARM based device (Xilinx Zynq-7020) and the client is a windows.

At the server side, when I bind, listen, and accept an address:port, the client can connect to and read/write from this address. And after program exit, idle for some short time (10s~30s) then start again, it can also read/write from the server. Howeber, when I exit the client, and idle for a long time (>30s), I cannot connect to the server anymore. And at the server side, it no longer accept any address. Any solutions ?

The code for the server side is listed below:

```
void echo_server( void *pvParameters )
{

    long lSocket, lClientFd, lAddrLen = sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );
    struct sockaddr_in sLocalAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

    static char dIn[BUF_SIZE];
    int ret;
    ( void ) pvParameters;

    int on = 1;
    int idle = 60;
    int intvl = 15;
    int cnt = 3;

    /* step 1. create and setopts */
    lSocket = lwip_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if( lSocket >= 0 )
    {
        lwip_setsockopt(lSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on));
        //lwip_setsockopt(lSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(idle));
        //lwip_setsockopt(lSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &intvl, sizeof(intvl));
        //lwip_setsockopt(lSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &cnt, sizeof(cnt));

        memset((char *)&sLocalAddr, 0, sizeof(sLocalAddr));

        // prepare bind on port
        sLocalAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sLocalAddr.sin_len = sizeof(sLocalAddr);
        sLocalAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        sLocalAddr.sin_port = ntohs( ( ( unsigned short ) ECHO_PORT ) );

        /* step 2. bind */
        if( lwip_bind( lSocket, ( struct sockaddr *) &sLocalAddr, sizeof( sLocalAddr ) ) < 0 )
        {
            lwip_close( lSocket );
            vTaskDelete( NULL );
        }

        /* step 3. listen */
        if( lwip_listen( lSocket, BACKLOG ) != 0 )
        {
            lwip_close( lSocket );
            vTaskDelete( NULL );
        }

        for( ;; )
        {

            /* step 4. accept */
            xil_printf("(ZYNQ-ECH) wait connection\n");
            lClientFd = lwip_accept(lSocket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &client_addr, ( u32_t * ) &lAddrLen );
            xil_printf("(ZYNQ-ECH) accept connection\n");

            lwip_setsockopt(lClientFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on));
            //lwip_setsockopt(lClientFd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idle, sizeof(idle));
            //lwip_setsockopt(lClientFd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &intvl, sizeof(intvl));
            //lwip_setsockopt(lClientFd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &cnt, sizeof(cnt));

            // if client socket created
            if( lClientFd > 0L )
            {

                int packet = 0;
                while(1)
                {

                    ret = mfeit_read(lClientFd, dIn);
                    if (ret == -1 || ret == 0)
                        break;

                    ret = mfeit_write( lClientFd, dIn, ret );
                    if (ret == -1 || ret == 0)
                        break;

                    packet ++;

                }
                xil_printf("(ZYNQ-ECH) close connection, total = %d\n", packet);
                lwip_close( lClientFd );
            }
        }
    }

    /* Will only get here if a listening socket could not be created. */
    xil_printf("(ZYNQ-ECH) task killed !!\n");
    vTaskDelete( NULL );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about that stuff, but first you need to set up proper way of keep-alive.

1. is keep-alive on server configured, so for how long he is persisting keep-alive
2. set proper time for keep-alive on your side.
3. Don't do keep-alive with 2hrs or someting. Create a new socket for that it's bad for server resources.

Comment: Hi, I tried keep alive with different options, such as  `int on = 1;
 unsigned int idle = 7200;    // in seconds
 unsigned int intvl = 3600;   // in seconds
 unsigned int cnt = 9;

 lwip_setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on));
 lwip_setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (void *)&idle, sizeof(idle));
 lwip_setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPINTVL, (void *)&intvl, sizeof(intvl));
 lwip_setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPCNT, (void *)&cnt, sizeof(cnt));` they all won't work. I googled and found that MAC address might be the issue where I set MAC manually.

Comment: (cont.) MAC address as 00-13-14-15-15-16 , and route the lwip application via a router to PC, can it be the problem ?

Comment: Hm, MAC could be a problem, but did you checked what is going on network via WireShark (https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or something? Connect it direct in your PC LAN and see whats going on. KEEP_ALIVE packets schould be sent if not than it's problem on device, if they are sent, than server does not accept keep-alive (i think it has to be configured, not sure).